# Showing join/part messages in weechat when they have been filtered

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, weechat

I'm using weechat with [smart filter](https://weechat.org/files/doc/devel/weechat_faq.en.html#filter_irc_join_part_quit) to hide join and part messages, but sometimes I would like to be able to disable the filter temporarily to see them, e.g., when I'm confused about these events. What is the way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut is `Alt+=` to toggle filtering; it's explained in the [weechat documentation](https://weechat.org/files/doc/stable/weechat_user.en.html) but it's rather hard to find unless you know what to look for.